# Auto ssd management available?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, ssd

I've just bought a SSD, and I was wondering if there is any program which auto-optimzes/maintains your SSD settings/environment. Or if  there exists a complete list with all the possible actions you could do in order to keep your SSD at top speed/condition. Since there are so many things you should keep in mind when using/maintaining a SSD(TRIM, changing pagefile dir, disable superfetch and everything) it's perfectly reasonable that you forget/pass over some of them.

Now there is an equally amount of threats which discuss all of these things, so that isn't really clearing things up. So it'd be very useful and easy to sum these up or put it into a program. In addition to that, is there a list of programs/features, which are well-know of their abundant randow-write's, so you can disable or delete them?
I'm certainly not a native english-speaker so feel free to suggest any edits.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The operating system provided it supports TRIM will do this automatically.  Since Windows 7 and Windows 8 both support TRIM thats not a concern.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 8 by default optimizes it's functions accordingly when installed on an SSD, so you wouldn't have to worry about it. On the other hand, Windows 7 IIRC does not have the same automatic optimizations. Also, when dealing with large SSDs (32 GB +) you don't have to worry so much about the drive's longevity (unless it's faulty, in which case you can't really do much), because it has been shown that even with the most stressful activity, a run-of-the-mill drive will last many years.

Comment: well if that would be true all those threats and sites with tips to improve your ssd life would be useless and unnecessary. I don't think that is true, and i suppose you will agree with this. Of course windows will have a number of features which optimze your ssd, but it certainly won't cover all possible actions. I do know about a lot of things you can do in order to maximize your ssd life but i'm looking for the complete list. Windows doesnt auto-disable superfetch and pagefile i suppose, and then there is still the list of well-known programs i'd like to know.

Comment: I'm sorry Bart, but I have to disagree. I do not think all topics revolving around improving your SSD life (especially in Windows 8) are useful at all these days. When SSD technology started picking up and higher capacity drives were put on the market, IMO, all topics concerning their optimization went obsolete for the reason I stated above in my post. Doing all the extra optimizations you are looking for will not improve the lifetime of your drive by enough in order for it to matter.

Comment: you've got a point that some or many of these posts may be obsolete, but there are tons of options and i find it hard to belive that windows will configure/cover everthing the way you'd want as a poweruser, and that ssd's are now maintenance-free. and many of these posts are still being updated. next to that, i suppose that there are still programs which perform a lot of random-writes on your ssd. And could you tell me if it's still recommended to align sectors on an ssd? (thanks for your efforts)

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough knowledge to tell you whether it's recommended to align sectors, and neither do I specifically know of any problematic programs.

Comment: then these kind of options are the ones which are still left after the obsolete threats. too bad that obsolete threat aren't deleted or marked as obsolete. it doesn't make things clearer. thanks for the help, hopefully there are people who do know about the less known problems and those programs/features.